# prevent html elements from squishing when resolution too small

Tags: html, css

I see websites like Amazon and Google when you shrink the width of the web browser the elements only squish to a certain point and then it stops squishing even if you shrink the width even more.

What kind of techniques would allow this? Is there a specific CSS attribute that can enable this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably seeing the `min-width` and `min-height` styles in action.

eg:

```
.myclass {
    width: 50%;
    min-width:100px;
}
```

...will take up 50% of the container object, so can be resized, but will never get smaller than 100px wide.

`min-height` works in much the same way.

Note that if you need to support IE6, this browser doesn't support `min-height` or `min-width`. (there are work-arounds for this, but the best solution is not to support IE6)

Answer (score 3):

The CSS [`min_width`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/min-width) property.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: How is this answer not the essential parts of the answer? Just because I don't provide an example? He asks for the specific CSS attribute and I provide it, and an additional link in the case that he wants more information.

Comment: While `min_width` is correct, look at the highest upvoted answer and you'll see why yours only got 1 upvote and that one got more. It's a more complete and better answer. That's the kind of answers we want here.

Comment: While I understand why I might not be the most useful answer, I highly doubt that my answer is not useful. Which is what a downvote would imply.

Comment: Downvotes don't imply it isn't useful. They also determine quality.

Answer (score 2):

```
#header {
  background: url(../images/image.jpg) repeat-x;
  min-width: 960px;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

They use the min-width and min-height css properties.

For example, to make a content div (or with HTML 5 a content tag) stop shrinking when its 300px wide, use the following css code:

```
div#content {
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

You can still use this method with a percentage or em based layout- just use it to prevent the page from becoming to small:

```
div#content {
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

Note: The min-width property does not include padding, borders, or margins when it calculates when to kick in (it only considers the container's width).