# Site width scaling

Tags: php, css, html

I think I have done a bad thing. On my site http://NWGlobalVA.com I have been playing with the idea of having the site scale with the width of the browser. I have now realized that this is a bad idea because my Elements bunch up and it starts to look terrible.

My issue is that I have backed myself into a corner when it comes to making this thing rigid again so that it doesn't scale. Does anyone have any advice on how I should do the above? I imagine it's something simple however I can't seem to find a way to lock down the elements so that everything displays okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having `class="bg"` to your outermost div for contents. If you do some CSS tricks to this class, your problem may solve. Following are some options you can try out.

1] Remove `margin-left: 200px;` and `margin-right: 200px;` from the css of this class and see the result. It will make the site full width regardless of the device width.

2] Try giving CSS as `width: 95%;` and `margin: 0 auto;`

3] If you want to make your site fully device-friendly,  [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is the best option.

4] If you want to go with current CSS rules then you can use **Media Queries** to handle the site dimensions according to the device.  [Here is the link for Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: wow that defiantly made the site display much better. I changed it from 200px to 50px just to add a little bit of white zone to the edges. I am curious. Do you know of a way that I could make the elements not squish? I think this is because most of the CSS that I did was 100% width and it scales with the browser when moved. Do you know of another way I could get around this?

Comment: Take a look at this link. It can answer your questions in more better way.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572465/prevent-html-elements-from-squishing-when-resolution-too-small